# String.prototype.myFunction not returning a string?

Tags: javascript, string, this, function-prototypes

Why does the below code not return *this* properly? It should just return 'image', rather than all of the letters in an object, shouldn't it?

```
String.prototype.removeExtension = function(){
    return (this.lastIndexOf('.') !== -1) ? this.substr(0, this.lastIndexOf('.')) : this;
}

'image.jpg'.removeExtension(); // returns 'image'

'image.png.jpg'.removeExtension(); // returns 'image.jpg'

'image'.removeExtension(); // returns String {0: "i", 1: "m", 2: "a", 3: "g", 4: "e", removeExtension: function}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/38Yu9/ (`this.toString()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` always references an *object* within the context of a scope <sup>(*)</sup>. You need to invoke `.toString()` for instance, to get the pseudo *primitive value* out of it.

```
return this.toString();
```

If you return `this` just like that, it'll reference the current instance of that `String-object` currently invoked.

---

<sup>(*) (only exception is ES5 strict mode, where `this` also might reference the `undefined` value</sup>

Comment: That simple? Thanks! But what I don't understand is why this.substr(...) will return a string, because I thought substr would only work for Strings, or does substr() do this.toString() internally?

Comment: @emma.fn2 pretty much. *Primitive values* internally get converted into their *Object representation* when you call something like `"Hello".substr()`. The method in turn, will return a new *primitive string value*.

Comment: "pseudo primitive value" What's the meaning of "pseudo" in this context? The primitive value looks quite concrete to me. Or do you mean in terms of JS not having actual primitives (as even "primitive" strings inherit from `String.prototype`)?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yes, pretty much the latter. Its somewhat inscrutable when we deal with a *primitive value* and when with its *Objectified* representation since ECMAscript will convert it under the hood at will. I guess thats what I meant. It still might be wrong wording, I'm uncertain.

Comment: We can understand perfectly, no problem. `=]`

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between a primitive [string value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.16) and a [`String` object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.15).

```
'foo'             // primitive

new String('foo') // object
```

When you call a String member function on a string primitive, it gets wrapped in a String object, which becomes the value of `this` within the function. (More on this behavior below.)

So, in `removeExtension`, `this` is a `String` object. On the other hand, the built-in function `this.substr` returns a primitive; that's just how it's defined. Thus, you see different things when you return `this` (`String` *object*) versus the result of `this.substr` (string *primitive*). If you want to return a string primitive version of the `this` object, just use `this.toString`.

You see the same wrapping behavior with any primitive, e.g., `Number`s:

```
Number.prototype.returnThis = function() { return this; }

typeof 2;               // 'number'
typeof (2).returnThis() // 'object' (a Number object, specifically)
```

If you really want to know why this happens, it's in the ECMAScript spec:

> **10.4.3 Entering Function Code**
>
> The following steps are performed when control enters the execution
>   context for function code contained in function object F, a caller
>   provided thisArg, and a caller provided argumentsList:
>
> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the `ThisBinding` to `thisArg`.
> 2. Else if thisArg is null or undefined, set the `ThisBinding` to the global object.
> 3. Else if `Type(thisArg)` is not Object, set the `ThisBinding` to `ToObject(thisArg)`.
> 4. ....

Point #3 is the important on there: calling functions on primitive values (i.e., non-object) coerces them into their corresponding object form.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behavior because String is not a char array. So

```
'image'.removeExtension();
```

will return a object string not {0: "i", 1: "m", 2: "a", 3: ...

to get a particular char use 
'image'.charAt(3); // g